# I want to group my pandas dataframe based on a list

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a data frame which has 2000+ records. I want to create another filtered data frame based on another list (top 10)

I have created the top 10 list on the original dataframe

```
venues_sort = venues_df.groupby(['Neighbourhoods'])['VenueCategory'].count()                             .reset_index(name='count').sort_values(['count'], ascending=False)            .head(10)
#top 10 neighbourhoods with maximum number of restaurants
venues_sort = pd.DataFrame(venues_sort)
```

I am unable to find a way to filter my data frame based on top10 list.

Comment: top10_neighbourhoodlist = []
top10_neighbourhoodlist = venues_sort['Neighbourhoods'].tolist()
print(top10_neighbourhoodlist)

Comment: This is how I am getting the top10 list. I want to use that in my groupby function on my original dataframe.

Comment: @DushyantSapre please add all the relevant code to your original question as formatted code snippets. also, where is your actual sort operation? it seems like something is missing

Comment: `venues_df.groupby(['Neighbourhoods'], as_index=False)['VenueCategory'].head(10)`?

Comment: I figured out: top10_neighbourhoodlist = []
top10_neighbourhoodlist = venues_sort['Neighbourhoods'].tolist()
#print(top10_neighbourhoodlist)
top10_venues_df = venues_df.loc[venues_df['Neighbourhoods'].isin(top10_neighbourhoodlist)]
top10_list = venues_df.loc[venues_df['Neighbourhoods'].isin(top10_neighbourhoodlist)]